# How do you connect to an existing database table in peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

Much of the tutorials I've read show how to connect to the database and create a *new* table. Maybe I am wrong or misunderstanding , Ive reading the documents here: [peewee offical](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html)

It shows how to connect to a db like so:

```
mysql_db = MySQLDatabase('my_app', user='app', password='db_password',
                         host='10.1.0.8', port=3306)
```

and it shows how to create a new table like so:

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField()
    join_date = DateTimeField()
    about_me = TextField()
```

But I want to know if I already have a database table with data in it how do I connect to it so I can add new records to it?

Thanks

Comment: Write a model class that accurately reflects what you have in your database, that's all there is to it. Then query the table through the model class. You can get some help auto-generating models using pwiz.

Answer (score 1):

Peewee does include a utility to look at an existing database and create model code to interact with that database. Here's a link describing it in the documentation: https://peewee.readthedocs.io/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#pwiz-a-model-generator .
I haven't used this so can't vouch for how well it works.